# Error with Bash script - syntax error

Tags: bash

File: test.sh

Command: sh test.sh

Content of test.sh

```
   x=1
    while [ $x -le 5 ]
    do
      echo "Welcome $x times"
      x=$(( $x + 1 ))
    done
```

Error:

> test.sh: line 6: syntax error near
>   unexpected token `done'
>
> test.sh: line 6: `done'

GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: RESOLVED: I tried to use "pico" instead of trasfering file via FTP and all works! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I run that code.

Make sure you're running with **bash** not **sh**. The `$(( ))` construct is relatively new.

Comment: Works for me under `sh` as well. My version of sh is 4.1.

Comment: @Rafe On some architectures, sh is a separate, less capable executable  than bash.

Comment: i have GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: RESOLVED: I tried to use "pico" instead of trasfering file via FTP and all works! thanks!

Comment: @Leonardo: Check your FTP line ending conversions. Line endings are significant to bash since a newline marks a new statement, and if the line endings are being translated incorrectly, the statements will be mixed up. You CAN explicitly terminate statements with semicolons, but you're better off just making your file transfers work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Run your script with:

```
bash test.sh
```

It will work.  There are two main possibilities:

- When it is run as `sh`, `bash` does not necessarily recognize all the syntax that it recognizes when it is run as `bash`.  On the Linux and MacOS X machines where I tested this, though, both `sh` and `bash` worked fine.
- Alternatively, you might be on a machine running AIX, HP-UX, Solaris or similar, where `/bin/sh` is not the same shell as `bash` at all.  It is more rigid Bourne shell, where the notation you used is invalid - a syntax error.

Comment: Look hard at the code, then.  Possibly, you have CRLF (DOS) line endings?  Even that's a bit of a stretch, though.  The Linux machine I tested on has bash 3.2.25(1) on x86/64.  Look at your code with `od -c`; there is ample evidence that what is copied and pasted is OK.  Maybe try typing it in again into test2.sh, and see if that works.  It sounds silly, but at this point, your problem is most peculiar.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange on my system I get.

```
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times
```

Must have something to do with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Say hello to semicolons. :)

```
x=1
while [ $x -le 5 ]
do
  echo "Welcome $x times";
  x=$(( $x + 1 ));
done
```

You don't need a semicolon if it's one line, however, you might want to do a loop this way:

```
for i in `seq 1 5`
do
  echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

Comment: The semi-colons are not relevant.

Comment: `seq` isn't needed in Bash: `for i in {1..5}` or `for ((i=1;i<=5;i++))`